# Is there a possibility to use switch like it is used for buttons also for checkboxes?

Tags: java, android

I want to simplify my code in AndroidStudio. For buttons I use

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and later

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_1:
        ..;
        break;
```

and so on

is there a similiar method for Checkboxes? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

First, implement `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` interface in your activity or fragment , then in `onCreate()` find your `CheckBox` and set an event for them like below.

```
 cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)
 cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)
```

finally, override a required method like below

```
override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
    if (buttonView?.id == R.id.cb1) {
        Log.e("CB1","CB1")
    } else if(buttonView?.id==R.id.cb2) {
        Log.e("CB2","CB2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use this method `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, it will give you 2 properties, the Button and isChecked boolean, you should use a switch statement for the boolean and define your own code logic for each state.

Answer (score 1):

For `CheckBox` also you can use `setOnClickListener()` method.

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox:
            if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                // code
            } else {
                // code         
            }
            break;
    }
}
```